# prisma generate : unable to resolve dependency tree (Prisma + Postgresql + NextJS)

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, yarnpkg, prisma

When I run `prisma generate` I get:

```
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: site@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2" from next@11.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"^11.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I have tried the command with --legacy-peer-deps, but it says:

> unknown or unexpected option: --legacy-peer-deps

I don't have any problems installing everything, I don't have any problems running the app. I also deleted the `node_modules` folder & `yarn.lock` file and tried a new `yarn install --legacy-peer-deps` but I'm still getting the same error. Also tried the aforementioned with `npm`. Now not sure what I could do anymore.

Comment: This likely doesn't have anything to do with Prisma generate. It's possible that when you run the command, npm can't seem to find the prisma cli in your project, so it attempts to install it and runs into the dependency issue. Could you check if both prisma or "@prisma/client" exists in your package.json and are available in ```node_modules```?

Answer (score 1):

`npm install @prisma/client` fixed it for me